# Text output doesn't save to file

Tags: java, netbeans, filewriter

When I run the code it gives me no errors, but it isn't writing to the file. Can someone please help me, it's not the first time this happens, but normally it's because I forget to close the FileWriter.

```
import java.io.*;
public class BrainfuckString {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence ="";
    char sentenceChar;
    int ASCIIChar;

    try
    {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("Hello1.txt"));

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) 
        {
            sentenceChar = sentence.charAt(i);
            ASCIIChar = Character.getNumericValue(sentenceChar); 
            writer.write(ASCIIChar);
        }
    writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
    catch(IOException I)
    {I.printStackTrace();}
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
i < sentence.length()
```

sentence.length is 0 so this will never be true.

Answer (score 2):

The `sentence` String is empty, so nothing is ever written to the file. Try changing so that the sentence is non empty.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence is "", empty string